# How can I get a unified git diff in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, diff, visual-studio-code

VS Code has a nice built-in Git interface, but it defaults to side-by-side file comparison/diff. Is there a way to switch to unified colored mode?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The [official view is a side by side one](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol#_viewing-diffs)

[image]

But the [VSCode Tips page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tips-and-tricks#git-integration) mentions

> ### Inline view
>
> Toggle inline view by clicking more button in the top right.

[image: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tips-and-tricks/raw/master/media/more_button.png] ("**`Inline View`**")

[image]

Comment: Of course, I'm blind. The specific menu item is: *Switch to Inline View*.

Comment: It's now called "Toggle Side By Side View" in the 3-dots menu

Comment: @LouisSt-Amour Thank you. i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: It's now showing up as "Inline View" in the "..." menu for me.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.